# USB-PD DRP from a single LiFePO4 cell

Tags: dc-dc-converter, lifepo4, usb-pd, powerbanks

I am about starting a project with LiFePO4 pouch cells. The idea is to create a powerbank from a single cell. The powerbank must have an input/output USB C connector with 65W minimum power (100W ideally). The idea is to charge laptops or charge the cell from the same connector.

I am searching all around and I don't find what I need to do such configuration. There are manufacturers like TI that have all-in-one solution (DC-DC+PD controller) but that chip works only as source and it is limited to 60W.

What I understand so far (maybe I am wrong) is that the PD controller handles the negotiation with the connected device giving a signal to the DC-DC to output the right voltage. However I don't get it yet how this is done, because then the DC-DC must be:

- Adjustable output
- buck-boost
- Compatible with the PD controller
- bidirectional (for the application I want)

The PD controller must also know which voltage is needed for the powerbank battery cell, if it is configured in a 3S Li-ion then the voltage for the DC-DC given to the cells must be 20V, if it is only one cell then it can be 5V.

Any advise?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: The communication of USB-PD has nothing to do with how your powerbank will be implemented. USB-PD is not the one that needs to know your battery voltage or construction. You simply negotiate the role of your device (charge or supply), at what voltage/current/power level. Then the rest of the powerbank knows to charge or supply power.

Comment: Ok, but maybe from that point comes my confusion. The PD controller negotiates the role and the voltage/current with the connected device. However, when the PD controller is set as sink, which voltage is then selected? Because it might be that I have a battery charger input ranging from 5 to 12V and the connected charger is able to deliver 20V/5A to the powerbank, then the PD Controller of the powerbank would accept 20V/5A. Unless there is some configuration to be done with the PD controller according to the setup.

Comment: Of course your PD controller asks what the supply supports and from the supported list you choose whichever suits best. The PD supply would not blinldly end 20V/5A unless you allow/request it. Otherwise a 20V capable charger would destroy 12V capable mobile phones for example.